# How can I create an app and add a shortcut to the desktop?

Tags: sitecore-client

I want to create an app that an author can access from the Desktop. How can I make one and insert it in there? I don't seem to find any documentation on that.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

## How to create an App

#### Create app Layout

1. Open `core` database
2. Go to: `/sitecore/layout/Layouts/Applications`
3. Create new Layout item (see existing examples, i.e `/sitecore/layout/Layouts/Applications/Content Manager`)
4. Create layout file on the disk (it should be located here: `Website\sitecore\shell\Applications`)
5. Link together file on the disk and item in the database either using `Path` field (if you will use aspx) or `Control` field with control name (if you use XML layout file).

**Note**
If you use Control mapping remember about proper naming inside XML. For example **LicenseOverview** application has something like this in the XML

[image]

#### Create app

1. Open `core` database
2. Go to: `/sitecore/content/Applications`
3. Create your app folder
4. Create app item
   [image]
5. Set previously created layout
   [image]

## Desktop shortcut

1. Open desktop and switch to core database (`http://domain/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?sc_content=core`)
2. Right click on desktop and select **Create Shortcut**
3. In link find your application (in my case: `/sitecore/content/Applications/Alan/AlanTest`)

[image]

## Start button shortcut

If you need your application shortcut to be present here

[image]

1. Open `core` database
2. Go to: `/sitecore/content/Documents and settings/All users/Start menu/Right`
3. Create your application shortcut and set a link to point on your application.

## Bonus: Launchpad shortcut

To add a shortcut to the Launchpad (`http://domain/sitecore/shell/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad`)

1. Open `core` database
2. Go to: `/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons`
3. Create `LaunchPad-Button` under some `LaunchPad-Group`

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: There is also a Documents and settings tree where you can place the shortcut.

Comment: Also, I guess we can make the page MVC right? Not just webforms? By the way, awesome example, thanks so much! @AlanPłócieniak

Comment: I am not sure. I've never tried it.